# Why do we have sixteen possible configurations of three saddles on one level?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, mapping-class-groups, morse-theory

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)) page 13 we have :

> There are **sixteen** possible configurations
> of three saddles on one level, shown in figure 10, where the saddles are regarded as
> 1-handles, or rectangles, attached to level curves. The sixteen configurations are grouped
> into eight pairs, the two configurations in each pair being related by replacing $f_{tu}$ by its
> negative.
> $$
> f_{t u}(x, y)=\pm x^{4} \pm\left(u-u_{0}\right) x^{2} \pm\left(t-t_{0}\right) x \pm y^{2}
> $$[image: Figure from p. 13 of Hatcher–Lochak–Schneps]

Why do we have **sixteen** possible configurations
of three saddles on one level ? why 16 ? how we can get this ? what does “negative of $f_{tu}$” mean ?

I think the negative of $f_{tu}$ is :$$
f_{t u}(x, y)=- x^{4} -\left(u-u_{0}\right) x^{2} -\left(t-t_{0}\right) x - y^{2}.
$$ is this true ?

Answer (score 1):

In this portion of the paper, the authors are concerned with the set of level preserving diffeomorphism classes of Morse functions on surfaces with at most three critical points. Index 0/2 critical points don't affect what they are interested in and, either way, can be easily dealt with. In addition, configurations resulting in multiple connected components are best analyzed one component at a time (which leads to the earlier two saddle case which you should understand first).

So we are left with the case of finding maps of connected surfaces with at most three index 1 critical points. The starting level consists of some number of circles, but since we have only three saddles to connect these circles and we want a connected surface in the end, we see that the maximum number of circles on the bottom is four. At this point it becomes straightforward combinatorics with each number of "lower circles."

I will walk you through the four circles on the bottom case and leave the rest for you. Draw four circles, call them $C_i$, at the bottom level. We now have three saddles to distribute and, since we need a connected surface, every saddle must join two distinct components. Up to reordering the circles there is actually no choice for the first two saddles, so that we can assume the first three circles are joined to each other by two saddles. For the third saddle, there is indeed a choice. There is one circle, $C_2$, with two saddles coming out of it and two circles $C_1$ and $C_3$ with one saddle coming out of them. Connecting $C_4$ to $C_1$ or $C_3$ gives you configuration (a) in your list and connecting $C_4$ to $C_2$ gives you configuration (b).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424188/about-two-surgeries-on-a-collection-of-circles

Comment: Why two configurations in each pair being related by replacing $f_{tu}$ by its
negative ? What is relation between $f_{tu}$ and  it's negative ?

Comment: Is this true that the number of $f_{tu}$ is  $2^4$ ,  so we have 16, $f_{tu}$?