# configurations of three saddles on one level

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, morse-theory, critical-point-theory, cerf-theory

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)) page 13 we have :

> There are **sixteen** possible configurations
> of three saddles on one level, shown in figure 10, where the saddles are regarded as
> 1-handles, or rectangles, attached to level curves. The sixteen configurations are grouped
> into eight pairs, the two configurations in each pair being related by replacing $f_{tu}$ by its
> negative.
> $$
> f_{t u}(x, y)=\pm x^{4} \pm\left(u-u_{0}\right) x^{2} \pm\left(t-t_{0}\right) x \pm y^{2}
> $$[image: Figure from p. 13 of Hatcher–Lochak–Schneps]

Why do we have **sixteen** possible configurations
of three saddles on one level ? why 16 ? how we can get this ? i think we have 20 possible configurations of three saddles on one level (up to level-preserving diffeomorphism). i draw 10 pairs (twenty figs) as follow :

also how can we get yellow cases with pairs "d" and "e" ?
[image]

Comment: How is this different from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424235/why-do-we-have-sixteen-possible-configurations-of-three-saddles-on-one-level ?

Comment: @LSpice . In this case i draw 20 confirmations.

Comment: @skupers . No i want to show why yellow cases are equal to d and e ?